# UndefinedFunctionError - iex aliasing in phoenix / ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

when i launch

```
iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

I would like to be able to run commands like:

```
iex(1) > Repo.all(MyModel)
```

However, this gives me this error:

```
(UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Repo.all/1 (module Repo is not available)
```

If I prefix my calls with my ProjectName, it works:

```
iex(1) > ProjectName.Repo.all(ProjectName.MyModel)
```

How can I avoid having to prefix my calls with my Project Name in iex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add code to the file `.iex.exs`, it'll get executed whenever you launch `iex` in that directory. So if you just add this to your `.iex.exs`:

```
alias ProjectName.{Repo, MyModel}
```

you'll be able to access `ProjectName.Repo` as `Repo` and `ProjectName.MyModel` as `MyModel`.

Comment: I get this error when i try it (with braces). 

`SyntaxError) .iex.exs:1: syntax error before: '{' `

It works ok without braces though if i put each alias on a separate line.

Comment: Is it possible to have a wildcard?  ie,

`alias ProjectName.*`

Comment: Are you on Elixir <= 1.1? The brace syntax was added in 1.2. You need to put them in separate calls (like you already figured out) in <= 1.1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to alias with wildcard, but the brace syntax should help a lot (compared to what we had in 1.1) when you upgrade to 1.2.